# Qual código HTTP eu devo usar quando não consigo autenticar em serviços de terceiros com login e senha providos pelo cliente anteriormente?

Tags: rest, http, restful, http-status

Estou implementando um serviço de um site que faz o seguinte:

- O meu site (A) conecta em alguns serviços externo providos por terceiros (B, C e D) usando webservices.
- Na verdade A é uma API REST no backend que é acessado pelo javascript do frontend. O frontend não necessariamente é o meu, o cliente pode desenvolver o seu próprio frontend acessando a minha API REST se assim ele preferir.
- Cada usuário do meu site A tem um login e senha no site B, um no site C e um no site D. Cada um desses logins e senhas dos sites B, C e D ficam salvos no meu banco de dados, por meio de uma funcionalidade oferecida ao usuário para este fim. Esses logins e senhas são diferentes entre si e diferentes do login e senha que uso para logar o cliente no site A.
- Há algumas funcionalidades que o cliente acessa no meu site A que dependem da integração com os serviços B, C e D, e neste momento o login e a senha do respectivo serviço integrado é usado.
- Por vezes, o login e senha enviados ao B, C ou D estão errados porque o meu usuário (do site A) os salvou incorretamente ao usar a funcionalidade que salva esses logins e senhas no banco de dados.

Pois bem, a minha dúvida é qual é o código de status HTTP que devolvo ao navegador do cliente quando o login e senha para a integração estão errados.

- [*400 - Bad Request*](https://httpstatuses.com/400) não parece ser bom porque isso é para requisições HTTP malformadas e a requisição recebida pelo meu site A é bem formada.
- [*401 - Unauthorized*](https://httpstatuses.com/401) não parece ser bom porque isso seria para uma falha de autenticação ou autorização no site A que é onde o navegador está se conectando. Ocorre que a falha de autenticação foi na integração com o site B, C ou D e não no site A. Além disso, em caso desse código ser aplicado, um cabeçalho `WWW-Authenticate` deveria estar presente para permitir o navegador a se (re)autenticar no meu site, o que não faz nenhum sentido no meu caso.
- [*403 - Forbidden*](https://httpstatuses.com/403) também não parece correto porque o cliente tem sim acesso a funcionalidade solicitada, o problema é apenas que ela não foi configurada adequadamente.
- [*404 - Page Not Found*](https://httpstatuses.com/404) também não é correto porque a página de fato existe e o cliente deve saber disso.
- [*405 - Method Not Allowed*](https://httpstatuses.com/405) também não é correto porque o método HTTP usado (GET, POST, PUT, etc) é o correto.
- [*406 - Not Acceptable*](https://httpstatuses.com/406) e [*506 - Variant Also Negotiates*](https://httpstatuses.com/506) também não parecem ser corretos porque isso tem a ver com o *content negotiation* que não tem relação com o problema ocorrido.
- [*407 - Proxy Authentication Required*](https://httpstatuses.com/407) também não parece ser correto porque isso diz para o cliente se autenticar em um proxy antes de tentar a requisição novamente com o site A. Ocorre que a requisição com o site A é válida e não precisa de proxy nenhum, o problema é entre A e B, C ou D.
- [*409 - Conflict*](https://httpstatuses.com/409) também não parece ser correto porque isso é para o caso de ocorrer um conflito entre duas ou mais requisições que alteram o estado do servidor.
- [*412 - Precondition Failed*](https://httpstatuses.com/412) e [*417 Expectation Failed*](https://httpstatuses.com/417) também não parece ser corretos porque isso tem a ver com o conteúdo dos cabeçalhos da requisição, que no meu caso não têm qualquer problema.
- [*421 - Misdirected Request*](https://httpstatuses.com/421) também não parece ser correto porque isso ocorre quando o servidor não é capaz de produzir uma resposta ao cliente, e não é esse o caso.
- [*422 - Unprocessable Entity*](https://httpstatuses.com/422) também não parece ser correto porque isso é para o caso de a requisição ter algum erro semântico. Ocorre que a requisição está correta afinal de contas.
- [*424 - Failed Dependency*](https://httpstatuses.com/424) é usado pelo WebDav no método PROPPATCH para especificar que a alteração de uma propriedade falhou porque isso desencadeou a alteração de uma outra propriedade e esta outra alteração falhou, tal como consta na [RFC4918](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4918.txt). Eu acho que usar isso para representar um erro de login e senha seria algo inadequado.
- [*500 - Internal Server Error*](https://httpstatuses.com/500) é para quando ocorre um erro imprevisto e não tratado no servidor, ou então para erros genéricos do lado do servidor. Não é esse o caso.
- [*502 - Bad Gateway*](https://httpstatuses.com/502) também não parece ser correto porque isso é para sinalizar uma resposta inválida do serviço integrado B, C ou D. Ocorre que a resposta de B, C ou D é válida, embora seja uma resposta de erro. Até faria sentido se o login e senha fossem algo privativos do site A com um desses outros sites, mas no caso eu estou usando um login e senha dados pelo cliente.
- [*503 - Service Unavailable*](https://httpstatuses.com/503) também não parece ser correto porque isso é para quando o servidor estiver congestionado ou em manutenção, o que não é o caso.
- [*510 - Not Extended*](https://httpstatuses.com/510) não parece ser correto porque após ler a [RFC2774](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2774.txt), isso daí tem a ver com extensões especificados em cabeçalhos da requisição. No meu caso não existe cabeçalho nenhum com qualquer propriedade especial relevante.
- [*511 - Network Authentication Required*](https://httpstatuses.com/511) também não parece ser correto porque isso é para quando ocorre um problema com a infraestrutura de rede do lado do cliente para ele obter acesso ao site A. No meu caso, se a requisição chegou ao site A, é porque ele já tem o acesso.
- Quanto aos códigos
  [*402 - Payment Required*](https://httpstatuses.com/402),
  [*408 - Request Timeout*](https://httpstatuses.com/408),
  [*410 - Gone*](https://httpstatuses.com/410),
  [*411 - Length Required*](https://httpstatuses.com/411),
  [*413 - Payload Too Large*](https://httpstatuses.com/413),
  [*414 - Request-URI Too Long*](https://httpstatuses.com/414),
  [*415 - Unsupported Media Type*](https://httpstatuses.com/415),
  [*416 - Request Range Not Satisfiable*](https://httpstatuses.com/416),
  [*418 - I'm a Teapot*](https://httpstatuses.com/418),
  [*423 - Locked*](https://httpstatuses.com/423),
  [*426 - Upgrade Required*](https://httpstatuses.com/426),
  [*429 - Too Many Requests*](https://httpstatuses.com/429),
  [*431 - Request Header Fields Too Large*](https://httpstatuses.com/431),
  [*451 - Unavailable For Legal Reasons*](https://httpstatuses.com/451),
  [*501 - Not Implemented*](https://httpstatuses.com/501),
  [*504 - Gateway Timeout*](https://httpstatuses.com/501),
  [*505 - HTTP Version Not Supported*](https://httpstatuses.com/505),
  [*507 - Insufficient Storage*](https://httpstatuses.com/507) e
  [*508 - Loop Detected*](https://httpstatuses.com/508),
  estes claramente não tem relação nenhuma com o meu problema.

Há alguns [status não-oficiais usados por aí](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#Unofficial_codes), mas nenhum deles parece se adequar também.

Assim sendo, nenhum dos códigos HTTP 4xx e 5xx oficiais que achei especificados em algum lugar parecem fazer sentido para o meu caso. Então, o que devo fazer? Que código HTTP devo utilizar e por quê? Se nenhum dos códigos de status oficiais forem adequados, seria melhor eu inventar um para isso ou forçar o uso de algum já existente? Se for forçar o uso de algum já existente, qual seria e por quê?

Além disso, noto que esse meu problema deve ser algo comum e recorrente, e portanto já deveria estar coberto em algum dos códigos existente.

Um outro ponto é que não tenho certeza se é problema no cliente (4xx) ou no servidor (5xx), uma vez que a requisição do cliente não pôde ser atendida devido a um problema na integração no lado do servidor (5xx), entretanto a razão de ocorrer essa falha é porque o cliente forneceu informações incorretas (4xx), mas essas informações não foram passadas pelo cliente no momento da requisição, e sim estavam armazenadas no lado do servidor (5xx).

Nota 1: Eu estou ciente das questões acerca de armazenar login e senha de clientes para serviços de terceiros ao invés de solicitá-los em cada requisição e das implicações em relação a segurança disso. Entretanto, o que estou pedindo tem pouca relação com isso.

Nota 2: Considerando-se os comentários e as duas respostas postadas, esclareço que não posso simplesmente retornar 200 indiscriminadamente para qualquer requisição para então impor ao cliente que interprete a resposta para saber se houve um erro ou não. Retornar um 400 para todo e qualquer erro e esperar o mesmo do cliente também está fora de cogitação. É um requisito importante que o código de status HTTP deva ser um código informativo.

Nota 3: Por enquanto, estou usando um código personalizado 432 para esta situação.

Comment: na minha opinião, HTTP Status refere-se ao seu website, e não dos serviços integrados. Se o site A está funcionando corretamente, a resposta deve ser 200, caso haja algum problema de integração por erro de digitação, o seu site A deve informar ao seu cliente que a integração não aconteceu por erro de digitação, e indicando que as configurações do perfil do cliente devem ser corrigidas. Se você retornar um erro 4xx ou 5xx, isso indicará um erro no seu site.

Comment: A resposta me parece simples - seu site é a referência de estado. Se funcional (integração não causa uma falha catastrófica) então você conseguiu gerenciar o estado: `200 OK`. Se a integração torna impossível a execução da ação, `500 Internal Server Error`. (Edit) O ponto do Ricardo é perfeito. Integrações são *parte da sua aplicação*.

Comment: @Ricardo Responder algo com um "200 Erro de autenticação" é meio estranho, não acha?

Comment: @OnoSendai Um `500 Internal Server Error` solicitando o cliente a configurar adequadamente o login e senha não é exatamente o que pode se considerar um erro interno do servidor.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Talvez eu não tenha me feito claro. Se as credenciais do usuário estão erradas, e o serviço remoto não as aceitou, isso não é um erro do seu sistema - você precisa implementar um fluxo que corrija a configuração. Entretanto, *sua aplicação ainda está funcional*; vocêe precisará guiar o usuário por um outro fluxo do processo, mas isso não implica num erro: `200 OK` indica que sua aplicação ainda funciona. A não ser que ela seja apenas um *proxy*.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, o cliente acessa o seu Site A, então, sempre que estiver online a resposta do seu site A será 200. Se a resposta dos outros serviços for diferente, você indica em uma página a resposta de cada serviço. Se você "assumir" o erro do site B ou site C, é o seu site A que está com problema.

Comment: Se a sua aplicação, entretanto, não possui um fluxo de tratamento para credenciais erradas e *falha catastroficamente* por causa disso, isso é um erro da aplicação (e `5xx` me parece válido.)

Comment: @OnoSendai Ok, editei a pergunta para clarificar isso. Na verdade a aplicação A tem duas partes, uma API REST no backend e o frontend. Se for só para a API conversar com o meu front, posso colocar o código que quiser e pronto, mas a minha dúvida é sobre o ponto de vista da API REST se for usada por outros aplicativos, qual seria o código mais adequado.

Comment: @Ricardo Veja o último comentário que fiz pro OnoSendai.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942951/rest-api-error-return-good-practices, mesmo tema, tem várias respostas e diagramas.

Comment: Eu sei que parece zoeira, mas eu sempre consulto os gatos HTTP https://http.cat/ para isso... A resposta real depende muito de como vai ser sua _implementação cliente padrão_, o modelo de consumidores do seu serviço.

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta bem heurística, seu caso em específico é um método não comummente utilizado. Pois bem, ao meu ver acredito que seja uma falha do servidor  5xx se não foi possível se comunicar com o os serviços de terceiro para autenticar. Porém, se seu serviço está funcionando e as credenciais fornecidas pelo usuário não estão sendo aceitas pelos serviços de terceiro, então é código 4xx na condição de que as credenciais não foram aceitas e por estarem incorretas ou foram fornecidas incorretamente.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho Sim, no primeiro caso que você citou, um 502 resolve. Já o segundo caso é que é o problema que descrevo na pergunta. Também cheguei a conclusão que isso é um 4xx porque é algo em que o cliente é que tem que atuar para resolver e a "culpa" é dele. Atualmente eu coloquei um código customizado 432 para essa situação.

Comment: As APIs 3rdparty podem ser configuradas pelo usuário final ou não? Quero dizer, ele pode alterar senhas do A, B, C e D sendo assim o possível responsável por falhas de autenticação?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, o usuário é que configurava as suas senhas para os serviços A, B, C e D. Entretanto, para ser sincero, já não estou mais envolvido com o projeto em questão, mas mesmo assim, ainda estou curioso em saber qual seria a melhor abordagem.

Comment: Eu não vou fazer uma resposta porque é apenas opinião minha e fazia um tempo que queria comentar sua pergunta. Penso eu que se o usuário depois de conectado no "A" acessa o "B" e "C" e pelo painel "A" pode ajustar e as mensagem de notificações com erros são informadas como sendo dos 3rdparty, então seria 403. Mas se a alimentação é um tipo de sincronização e os ajustes tem que ser feito diretamente por paineis nos 3rdparty então seria 500, isso porque para o servidor "A" a situação é inesperada e o processo é indireto. Espero que eu tenha conseguido explicar meu ponto de vista :)

Answer (score 3):

Como você faz múltiplas operações, algumas funcionam e outras não, você pode utilizar o multi status (207) e listar os status apropriados por operação.

Comment: Abordagem interessante. Não sei o que pensar sobre ela ainda. Vou refletir um pouco.

Answer (score 2):

Eu considero que **403 (Forbidden)** faz sentido nesse caso. Já cheguei a usar 400 (Bad request) em casos parecidos – é pouco preciso, mas ainda acho aceitável.

A justificativa para o uso da faixa 4xx é que se trata sim de um erro do cliente, apesar de detectado no servidor. Foi o cliente (o usuário, não o software que ele está usando) que informou credenciais incorretas.

Answer (score 1):

Um usuário havia postado uma resposta, porém ele a apagou. Pessoalmente, não concordo com ela porque não acho correto retornar 200 em caso de erro, mas de qualquer forma, copio a resposta apagada dele aqui do jeito que estava quando foi apagada para que o conteúdo não seja perdido:

> Depois de ler sobre o assunto:
>
> - http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2012/08/http-status-codes-and-restful-api-crafting
> - http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/common-rest-api-error-codes
> - http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/
>
> eu ficaria com a resposta encontrada no último:
>
> > There’s a lot of smart people at Facebook and they built an API that only ever returns 200.
> >
> > The basic argument against bothering with specific status codes is this: the existing status codes are much too general for a modern website/API
>
> Traduzindo: Os códigos de status são muito vagos para as aplicações modernas.
>
> A Microsoft apresenta 25 possíveis situações para o Código 400.

Answer (score 0):

Eu iria de **500**. Explico.

Pense que quem está integrando com sua API "A" não se importa - pelo que entendi da sua pergunta - com a autenticação para estas APIs internas. O fato é que o usuário da sua API tentou fazer uma requisição e não conseguiu completá-la.

Como uma 401 é mais esperada para a request atual e todos 4xx são *Client Errors*, eu trataria este problema como um erro imprevisto no servidor. Ou seja, um erro 500. Como está no link que enviou:

> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from
>   fulfilling the request.

Parece ser uma condição inesperada. Não há nada que o usuário possa fazer no rest service de "A" e o suporte (ou equipe de desenvolvimento) precisará atuar para resolver a situação. Para ajudar, adicione ao retorno do erro uma mensagem (ou código de erro) com a explicação: a autenticação a um sistema interno não foi possível de ser completada por um problema de usuário ou senha para a API B/C/D (se puder fornecer estes detalhes, claro).

Mesmo que não concorde com a minha resposta, tenha em mente que nem sempre você vai encontrar o código HTTP ideal para o seu problema. Um exemplo: qual código HTTP usar para validar se um campo de um cadastro é maior que o permitido? Verá que há uma boa discussão na Internet sobre isto.

O ideal é escolher o código HTTP que fizer mais sentido para você e estabelecer ele como padrão para o problema que está resolvendo.

Comment: Não concordo. O erro no caso é culpa do cliente, e não do servidor. E também não é um erro imprevisto. Pensando bem, o meu problema corresponde a uma classe de erros onde a requisição não obtém sucesso porque o cliente deve primeiramente realizar outras ações antes de tentar efetuar a requisição novamente (ações essas que não são simplesmente se autenticar no servidor). Assim sendo, tendo a pensar que um código 4xx seria adequado. Quanto à validação, sei que há um debate forte entre o 400, o 422 e outras alternativas.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, se o cliente pode tomar alguma ação, creio possa entender como ClientError mesmo (4xx). Preciso olhar deste ponto de vista o problema novamente, mas parece que o 401 seria a melhor escolha.

Answer (score -1):

Realmente não parece ter um código que atenda essa situação, já que no seu caso a requisição será processada corretamente.

Acredito que código 200 seja o mais indicado, com uma mensagem de erro personalizada.

Comment: Código 200 é OK,  significa que tudo está certo, sinal verde, etc. A situação requer um código de falha de autenticação ou erro interno do servidor.